# How to get an access token to send FCM through a proxy?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, http-proxy

I'm new to FCM and coding a java program to push messages. My App server is at our company premises and internet access via a proxy server. My problem is how can I get access token via a proxy? below is the code snippet

```
private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
  GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
      .fromStream(new FileInputStream("service-account.json"))
      .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));

  googleCredential.refreshToken();

  return googleCredential.getAccessToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with usage of anonymous HttpTransportFactory implementation:

```
var proxyUrl = URI.create(YOUR_PROXY);
var googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("service-account.json"),
        () -> new NetHttpTransport.Builder()
        .setProxy(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort())))
        .build()
    )
    .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
    .refreshAccessToken();

googleCredentials.refresh();
return googleCredentials.getAccessToken();
```

Note that it uses `GoogleCredentials` instead of `GoogleCredential` as at the time of writing this answer the later is deprecated.

edit:
Since you need to provide credentials for the proxy the solution gets more complex, but this is actually what I finally used:

```
private HttpTransportFactory getHttpTransportFactory(FirebaseProperties properties) {
    if (properties.getHttpProxy() == null) {
      return ApacheHttpTransport::new;
    }

    var proxyUrl = URI.create(properties.getHttpProxy());
    HttpHost proxyHostDetails = new HttpHost(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort());
    HttpRoutePlanner httpRoutePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxyHostDetails);

    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = ApacheHttpTransport.newDefaultHttpClientBuilder()
        .setRoutePlanner(httpRoutePlanner);

    if (isNotBlank(properties.getHttpProxyUser())) {
      CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
      credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHostDetails.getHostName(), proxyHostDetails.getPort()),
          new UsernamePasswordCredentials(properties.getHttpProxyUser(), properties.getHttpProxyPassword()));

      httpClientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(ProxyAuthenticationStrategy.INSTANCE)
          .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
    }

    return () -> new ApacheHttpTransport(httpClientBuilder.build());
}
```

where `FirebaseProperties` is just custom `@ConfigurationProperties` class holding data needed for proxy connection. Then you can just use `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(getHttpTransportFactory(properties)).createScoped(MESSAGING_SCOPE)` to create the credentials object